# Side bar width doesn't respond 100% width Clickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with my code. I'm trying to make my width work like it should but the width doesn't want to stay at 15%. I get it from 100% to 15% when you scroll down.

This is my side bar code:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="width: 15%">
    <div class="metro" >
        <nav class="sidebar (light)">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Welcome Your Username!</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="">Profile Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Tracking Log</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="/sheridan">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sheridan/news">News</a></li>

                <li><a href="/sheridan/memberlist">Members List</a></li>

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Application Development</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/app/assembler">Assembly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/app/c">C,C#,C++</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/app/java">Java</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/app/linux">Linux</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Web Development</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/web/html">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/web/js">Javascript</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/web/php">PHP/MySQL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Math</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/math/calculus">Calculus</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/math/discrete">Discrete Math</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/math/statistic">Statistic</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="">R</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Article</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/submit">Create An Article</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/getCode">Article Approval</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Picture</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/picture">View Picture</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Upload A Picture</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/sheridan/picture/approval">Picture Approval</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tested it everything was working fine. But now nothing want to work. I have been trying to figure it out for 1h and nothing is working...

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

You can view it at https://www.jmdev.ca/sheridan/ and the working version at https://www.jmdev.ca/sheridan/test/

Comment: whats the actual issue?

Comment: Go on the website you will see it pretty fast. The width is almost always 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong element. This is what you actually want:

```
<nav class="sidebar (light)">
```

It's set to `position: fixed` which is why it is ignoring it's parent width of `15%`. The properties on `.sidebar` are as followed:

```
.metro .sidebar {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: #3D3D3D;
   width: 100%; <------------- this
   height: 100%; 
}
```

Adjust the `width` and that should correct it

Comment: Thanks! It work. Now the only thing that doesn't work is when I click on the button that should drop down.

Comment: @Jean-Mathieu which button are you talking about?

Comment: Example you click On Math. There should be a drop down. (On the side bar) Like it does does on my testing version: https://www.jmdev.ca/sheridan/test/

Comment: @Jean-Mathieu It appears to be some kind of error in your javascript that is likely breaking before this and stopping this from working. I'm not that familiar with bootstrap so you may want to post a different question for that answer. In the mean time can you check this one off as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

```
.metro .sidebar 
    {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background-color: #3D3D3D;
       width: 275px;
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
```

- List item

Just Replace This css In Metro-bootstrap.css File